# Making a TabNav work correctly

Tags: html, css, tabnavigator

commerce site that has a particular tab navigation code that allows users to click and view information.

The Tab Nav looks like this:

Details | Shipping | Returns | Lifestyle View

When you click on anyone of these a paragraph appears below the tab with more information.  What happens though is that all the other list items get pushed below the paragraph rather than staying in their current positions.  So for instance if I click on "Details," the "Shipping," and "Returns," tab gets pushed down.  I would like all the menu items to stay intact and just have the paragraph appear below each menu.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

the page can be found at:

http://babsandmickieco.myshopify.com/collections/clothing-all/products/sana-dress#

Answer (score 1):

As I've demonstrated in [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vcGcz/), it really is a case of just appending an in flow element onto the list item. In the example I have provided, I used the following jQuery code to append a paragraph element (`P`) to a List item element (`li`).

**Snippet**

```
$("#clickAble").click(function(e) {    
    $("#clickList").append($("<p id='appended'>Hello</p>"));
});
```

As you can see, it's fairly obvious what his does. This created something of a rough example, but it's a working example nonetheless.